# Finding radius of convergenc of a power series expansion

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series

I am trying to solve the following problem but have no idea how to approach it. I was wondering if anyone could give me any hint or suggestion.

Suppose $f(z)$ is analytic at $z=0$ and satisfies $f(z) = z+ f(z)^2$. What is the radius of convergence of the power series expansion of $f(z)$ about $z=0$?

Comment: Derive the equation n times and evaluate at zero. Or put in $f(z) = \sum_n a_nz^n$ and sort by coefficients.

Comment: Setting $Z=f(z)$, solve the quadratic equation $Z^2-Z-z=0$, then ...

Comment: Thanks JeanMarie, I tried doing what you suggested, but I'm still stuck in the next step.